# Php character coding

Tags: php, centos

I have a file named index.php which using a mysql server gets a simple username. The mysql server is running on centOS and I have two different systems running apache serving as web servers.

One is my own windows pc using a "wamp" solution which uses the mysql server refereed before and the other is the centOS server itself.

I use this so I can develop in my laptop and run the final on the centOS box.

The problem is this:

Accessing centOS box I get (on hxxp://centos):

```
out_sider 1lu�s 2oi
```

Using wamp on windows I get (on hxxp://localhost):

```
out_sider 1luís 2oi
```

The mysql database is configured correctly seeing that both use the same and I used svn repository to move files from windows to centOS so the file is the same.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advnce

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is its probably a locale thing, try adding or updating locale settings of the centOS, or try controlling it from PHP.

```
str = iconv(mb_detect_encoding(str)/*or insert the encoding type if you know it*/, "UTF-8", str);
```

and try also:

```
str = mb_convert_encoding (str, "UTF-8");
```

Also try connecting and querying the MYSQL server directly, to rule out the fact that it maybe the MYSQL table charset (on centOS) or something.